# How to name introductory statement for a research paper?

Tags: research-process, citations, authorship, supervision, introduction

I have written a research paper and was told that I should include a preamble at the start explaining who had the idea for the project, who my supervisor was and the name of the company.

My question is how should I name this small section and where should I put it is with respect to the title page and abstract page?

I have already written an acknowledgments section and put it at the end of the paper, but that is separate.

Comment: Is this a peer-reviewed publication to be submitted to a scientific journal? If that's the case, study the author instructions of the journal.

Comment: I think you've been given incorrect instructions.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience (pure math, so usually not a company but a university), the most common place for this preamble information is a footnote on the article's first page.  The second most common place is in the acknowledgments. In either case, he usual formulation is something like "The results in this paper are from the author's doctoral dissertation, written at University X under the supervision of Y."

Comment: Yes, something on the order of a footnote is about right. No compulsion to have it be any sort of "named section" in the paper itself. Though, still, a similar sentence (as in @AndreasBlass' answer) at the end of the introduction, as a small separate paragraph, would have the same function... e.g., if footnotes are not acceptable in whatever style guide you're using.